# ORA-29471 DBMS_SQL access denied

Tags: oracle, plsql, privileges

ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied while executing procedure remotely.

i have 2 procedures procA & procB defined on DB A and DB B. i am trying to call procB from ProcA using dblink. procB is using DBMS_SQL.open_cursor, DBMS_SQL.PARSE & EXECUTE etc. to execute sql statement. procB works as expected when run from DB B however remote procedure procB fails with ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied.

i have a CLOB data (sql statements) on DB A which i am reading from Db B and storing it in local temp table for further operations.

i can see CLOB getting saved in temp table and there is no problem reading it.

I have checked roles for this user on both databases and there is no difference. Executed procB on DB B and it runs fine and complete its task. tried adding AUTHID CURRENT_USER.

not sure what i am missing in my code.

procA

````
      CURSOR c1
      IS
         SELECT SQLTEXT, REQUEST_ID, RNUM
           FROM FDP_SQL_SS_SQL_RECORD_HIST
          WHERE request_id = requestid;
   BEGIN
      FOR counter IN c1
      LOOP
            IF dbname = '21D' then
.
.
.
         elsif dbname = '22D' then
            BEGIN
                MY_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_PROC@MYREMOTEDBLINK (counter.request_id,counter.rnum,proc_output);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL executed '|| proc_output);
                COMMIT;
                IF SQLCODE > 0 THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error executing code on remote node');
                END IF;
            END;
            END IF;
      END LOOP;

--procB
rmt_cursor_name := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE (rmt_cursor_name, sqlstatement, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
   rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (rmt_cursor_name);
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR (rmt_cursor_name);
-- here sqlstatement has CLOB data saved into temp table.```
````

Comment: Privileges obtained through a role are not active inside PL/SQL. You need to grant the execute privilege _directly_ to the user (not through a role)

Comment: Thanks. Checking on this

Comment: I got my code working by removing output variable from procB however now i dont have any way to get success code/message from this procedure.  is any know workaround to achieve this?

Comment: The error `ORA-29471` sometimes happens when there's a weird error, like when `DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR` is missed.  Those errors sometimes don't go away until you close and re-open your connection.  Does this problem happen all the time, or is it intermittent?  Also, can you use `execute immediate` instead of `DBMS_SQL`, it's much simpler.  Finally, it might help to make a minimal reproducible example.